# SQL Update with row_number() plus concat

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, row-number

I add a new colum based on the values of another one. I'd like to update that new colum with the corrunt value plus an incremental number group by element.
For example:

| city | new_colum |
| --- | --- |
| Madrid | Madrid |
| Madrid | Madrid-2 |
| Madrid | Madrid-3 |
| Sevilla | Sevilla |
| Sevilla | Sevilla-2 |
| Sevilla | Sevilla-3 |
| Sevilla | Sevilla-4 |
| Alicante | Alicante |

I try the following code but I always get a syntax error.

```
UPDATE cities as c
SET c.new_colum = concat(t.city,'-', t.col) 
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by city) AS col, city_st FROM cities) t;
```

Comment: may be use a CTE and then update from that?

Comment: What is your _database_ (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, etc.)?  SQL is just a language, not an actual product.

Comment: Please state the DBMS so we can tell you exactly how to achieve what you are trying to. But for starters, you cannot create a new column during the update. You can only update existing columns.

Comment: My database is mysql.

Comment: I tried with cte but is not working @huMptyduMpty: with cte (col)
as (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by city ORDER BY city) AS col FROM cities)
update cities as c
set c.new_colum = concat(c.new_column,'-', cte.col) ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have added 'newcolumn' to cities and that there is a primary key in cities called 'id' then:

```
UPDATE cities c
JOIN
(SELECT id,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by city ) newcolumn
FROM cities) t on c.id=t.id
SET c.newcolumn = CONCAT(city,'-',t.newcolumn)
;
```

db-fiddle:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dTnf3bNaXhEKKDzZzSED9K/0